# remove specific elements from array Jlist above code

Tags: java

I  want to remove a item from array output in jlist

```
String[] cdList = {"Adele", "Drake", "Prince", "Rihanna", "Sia"}  ;
```

output

```
String[] cdList = {"Adele", "Drake", "Prince", "Sia"}  ;
```

Comment: Arrays have a fixed length. You probably want an `ArrayList<String>`. You could also make a copy of the array which has `length - 1` and skip the element you want to remove.

Comment: Have you tried iterating with a for loop and checking if it matches on each cycle?

Comment: Can you give some details about your array and what you're trying to do? Is the array intentionally sorted? Are you removing by index or by value? Could there be duplicates of the item being removed, and would you like to remove all occurrences if there are? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: hi I am trying to figure out a way to remove a specific Item from an array list . In GUI program. The  array is sorted. I want the code to allow the user to select a name from my array list and by pressing the remove  button I want it to disappear. If this helps you understanding my question.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cdList));
list.remove(cdList[i]);
cdList = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

I've written it like this,enjoy!

```
String[] cdList = {"Adele", "Drake", "Prince", "Rihanna", "Sia"}  ;

for(int i = 0; i< cdList.length;i++){
    System.out.println(i+1 + " . " + cdList[i]);
}
System.out.println("Enter the number of the name you want to remove:");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = scan.nextInt();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cdList));
list.remove(cdList[num-1]);
cdList = list.toArray(new String[0]);
for(int i = 0; i< cdList.length;i++){
    System.out.println(i+1 + " . " + cdList[i]);
}
```

cheers!